# Delete entries from database in certain parts of the day

Tags: php, mysql

So, I am building a website where people can search for places and check in to those places.
I want every entry deleted (or altered) when users day ends.

For example, my time is 20:00 and I submit a check in. I want it deleted in 00:00. Also, some other users time is 22:00 for example, I want his deleted in 00:00, but not 00:00 in my time, but his.

I hope I clarified the problem, I gave my best.
Is there even a way to do this or not?

Answer (score 0):

mhhh the question is whether you  have the right to run cronjobs. If it is the case that you can run cronjobs i would create a time zone entry in you're mysql db.

And see if the timestamps in the db for the user are equal to the current timme stamp (example using utc timestamps). And delete the entry if this is applicable

Here's the gist of how i would implement it In a rudementery form.

**timestamp**  current

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$now = new DateTime();
echo $now->getTimestamp(); //Unix timme stamp
```

**mysql**

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE timestamp <= $now
```

**after delete**

you can set the new utc time stamp of the next day

```
$value="00:00:00"; //just as an example use time zone from mysql table 
$timeStamp = strtotime('tomorrow ' .$value);

/*insert into mysql table structure*/
```

**as for the crone job**  that is supposed to execute hourly

```
0 * * * * fille.php
```

I hope this met you're expectations.I gave my best too ;).